# listview and edittext softkeyboard

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have custom template with edittext field. When I click on "next" button on softkeyboard it move focus only two time - than button changed to "OK". List have 12 items. 
Any way to navigate to all items, not only 2?
Can you help me please?

Im use this template for listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/head"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:width="100dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this xml for listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/head"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calk_1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="382dp"
        android:divider="@color/reddivider"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/twodp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, here my adapter right now:

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

```
// assign the view we are converting to a local variable
View v = convertView;

// first check to see if the view is null. if so, we have to inflate it.
// to inflate it basically means to render, or show, the view.
if (v == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null);
}

/*
 * Recall that the variable position is sent in as an argument to this method.
 * The variable simply refers to the position of the current object in the list. (The ArrayAdapter
 * iterates through the list we sent it)
 * 
 * Therefore, i refers to the current Item object.
 */
CalcItem i = objects.get(position);
int last=getCount()-1;

if (i != null) {

    // This is how you obtain a reference to the TextViews.
    // These TextViews are created in the XML files we defined.

    TextView hd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.head);
    TextView tx = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    TextView ds = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
    EditText vl = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.value);

    if (position==0){
        vl.setNextFocusUpId(last);
        vl.setNextFocusDownId(1);
    } else  if (position==last){
        vl.setNextFocusDownId(0);
    } else {
        vl.setNextFocusDownId(position+1);
    }

    if (hd != null){
        hd.setText(i.getHead());
    }
    if (tx != null){
        tx.setText(i.getText());
    }
    if (ds != null){
        ds.setText(i.getDescription());
    }
    if (vl != null){
        vl.setText(Integer.toString(i.getValue()));
    }
}

// the view must be returned to our activity
return v;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:nextFocusUp="id"` and `android:nextFocusDown="id"` - as described in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html).

Here's an example from the docs:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ... >
  <Button android:id="@+id/top"
          android:nextFocusUp="@+id/bottom"
          ... />
  <Button android:id="@+id/bottom"
          android:nextFocusDown="@+id/top"
          ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. I change my adaptor code but nothing - it not work. I update my question

Comment: Do you need to use a listview - or would a scroll view work since you know you're always only going to have 12 items?

Comment: I have two activity with difference count of items. One have 23 items and other 30.. Also quantity of items can be changed in shot future.

Comment: Gotcha, the only other thing that I can think of that might help, is to make sure you specify an inputType for each field that you want to be focused.  Honestly, though, I've never tried implementing this sort form from within a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Edit texts doesnt work well in ListViews and Recycler views, 
I'll Recommend you to inflate separate views multiple times instead of making a ListView if you are dealing with edit texts.